# Searching through an acyclic graph with minimum time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

Given a city network in the form of an acyclic graph, there are N cities and each city has a unique ID, which is an integer that ranges from 1 to N/ There exists N-1 unique paths between each pair of cities. The population of each city is provided.

Given Q queries, the number of cities that have a population smaller than or equal to W on the path from node U to node V should be returned. Here, U and V are the given cities' ID.

For example, consider N = 3, with a population of [1, 2, 3] each node. Node connections are: [[1, 2], [2, 3]]. Given a single query (Q = 1) and a set of U, V, W is given as: [[1, 3, 2]].

Across the path from node 1 to 3, since there are two cities having a population smaller than or equal to 2, the answer will be 2.

My approach uses Depth-First-Search.

```
int *city_population(int N, int *population, int **road, int Q, int **cities)
{
    int *city_count = (int *)calloc(Q, sizeof(int));
    int *path = (int *)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    int *visited = (int *)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    int u, v, w, pathIdx, pathFound, count;

    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++)
    {
        pathIdx = 0;
        pathFound = 0;
        count = 0;

        // u is the starting node
        u = cities[i][0];
        // v is the stopping node
        v = cities[i][1];
        // w is the max population
        w = cities[i][2];

        DFS(N, u - 1, v, population, visited, road, path, &pathIdx, &pathFound);

        if (pathFound)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pathIdx; j++)
            {
                if (population[path[j]] <= w)
                    count++;
            }
        }

        city_count[i] = count;

        reset_array(visited, N);
        reset_array(path, N);
    }

    free(path);
    free(visited);

    return city_count;
}

void DFS(int N, int startIdx, int stopIdx, int *population, int *visited, int **road, int *path, int *pathIdx, int *pathFound)
{
    int connection;

    visited[startIdx] = 1;
    path[*pathIdx] = startIdx;
    (*pathIdx)++;

    if (startIdx + 1 == stopIdx)
    {
        *pathFound = 1;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1 && !*pathFound; i++)
    {
        connection = road[i][1];
        if (road[i][0] == startIdx + 1 && !visited[connection - 1])
            DFS(N, connection - 1, stopIdx, population, visited, road, path, pathIdx, pathFound);

        else
        {
            connection = road[i][0];
            if (road[i][1] == startIdx + 1 && !visited[connection - 1])
                DFS(N, connection - 1, stopIdx, population, visited, road, path, pathIdx, pathFound);
        }
    }

    if (!*pathFound)
        (*pathIdx)--;

    visited[startIdx] = 0;
}

void reset_array(int *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
}
```

Although this approach works for a small N value, apparently it doesn't when the value of N gets exponentially large, over the extent of 6 digits. If that's the case, which implementation should be used for constructing a search algorithm that has minimum time complexity?

Some recommend implementing Breadth-First-Search, the others recommend changing the 2D data structure - road - to something less resource-consuming. Some suggest using Heavy-Light Decomposition, though I'm unaware of which approach to be the most suitable.

Comment: Before you get into optimizing the time performance, you need to look at the memory requirement of your code - which is enormous!  Have you tested this on a large graph,> 1000 nodes?

Comment: There are a number of aspects of your code that need work.  I would start with the the DFS parameter list, which is far too long.  You will quickly run out of stack space.

Comment: "the number of cities that have a population smaller than or equal to W on the path from node U to node V"  Since there are more than one path between two cities, this is undefined.  Perhaps you meant "on the shortest path"?

Comment: Re “There exists N-1 unique paths between each pair of cities”: Do you mean there are N−1 edges total? If there are multiple paths between each pair of cycles, why do you say the graph is acyclic? If there are two paths from A to B, then taking one path from A to B and the reverse of the other path from B to A forms a cycle, unless the edges are directed.

Comment: If the graph is in fact a *connected* acyclic graph (that is, a tree) with *N* nodes then it will indeed have exactly *N*-1 edges.  If it is acyclic but not connected then it will have fewer edges.

Comment: Yes, you definitely can't use an adjacency matrix. BFS is the wrong approach. Heavy-light will work but incurs an extra log factor compared to dynamic trees (which probably doesn't matter here).

Comment: I suspect this is some online code challenge, and the solution is something like to compile the tree into a simple database from which the desired result can be computed easily for any two nodes, after which the Q queries can be processed quickly instead of by searching the original tree.

Comment: Memoization or Dynamic Programming should be considered.

Answer (score 1):

> Although this approach works for a small N value, apparently it doesn't when the value of N gets exponentially large, over the extent of 6 digits. If that's the case, which implementation should be used for constructing a search algorithm that has minimum time complexity?

An acyclic graph with *N* nodes has up to *N*-1 edges.  For each node your DFS traverses, it scans the entire edge list, for O(*N*<sup>2</sup>) asymptotic complexity overall.  This is the primary place where there is room for an algorithmic improvement.

**One alternative** would involve

- including both directions of each edge in the edge list, and
- pre-sorting the edge list by start node

Then, instead of scanning the whole list when processing each node, you could use a binary search to find the edges outgoing from that node.  That would reduce the asymptotic complexity to O(*N* log*N*).

This does double the storage requirement for the edge list, but that's not going to be an issue unless you are already pushing up pretty close to your limit.

**Another alternative** would involve

- representing the edges by giving each node a list of all the nodes connected to it (each one of size proportional to the number of connected nodes)

Then, the DFS won't need to search at all to find the outgoing edges from any node.  No more than *N* nodes will be traversed, so this reduces the asymptotic complexity to O(*N*).

---

Note also that even with one of those improvements, **your DFS is susceptible to issues with unfortunately shaped graphs**.  For example, consider a connected acyclic graph in which no node has more than two edges.  Such a graph contains one path that traverses every single node without backtracking.  If you have to worry about tens or hundreds of thousands of nodes, then your DFS is likely to run out of stack space trying to recurse so deeply.  Either one of the suggested improvements would allow you to introduce limited protection against this by iterating instead of recursing when the current node has only one (unvisited) successor to visit.  It would still be possible, however, to construct a graph for which the DFS could go to linear depth.

**Additional possible improvements** include

- Define a structure type containing the graph details -- number of nodes, weight (population) of each node, and whatever representation of the edges you choose.  Pass around a pointer to that, instead of passing each item individually.
- Since your graph is acyclic, you don't need to keep track of *all* visited nodes.  Each call to `DFS()` only needs to know the immediate predecessor node.  As long as it does not return to that node directly, nothing deeper in the recursion will return to it (or any previous node) either.
- You don't need to record a path.  The DFS can instead keep track of the required count of small populations as it goes, obviating any need to traverse the path again to count populations.
- `DFS()` does not presently return anything.  You could modify it to use its return value instead of an `out` parameter to indicate whether it reached the target node.